# attribute error 'function' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Tags: python, django

i have been encountered by this error

> 'function' object has no attribute 'has_header'

my url file contans

```
 url(r'^HighDefs/$', list_HighDefs),
```

and i have a view defined with the name

> list_HighDefs

in views file. I dont know whats wrong.

the view contains

```
def list_HighDefs(request):
user_logger = Logger()
user_logger.log_stack()


if user_object:
    email = user_object.email
    uname = user_object.first_name+' '+user_object.last_name

    try:
        row = allapps_models.highdef.objects.filter(user_email=email, show_status=1)


    except Exception:

         return error_page(request)

    highdefs = []

    for m in row:
        order_product = int(m.m_id)
        state = m.state

        try:
            category = checkout_models.state.objects.get(pk=product).premature.category.all()
            category = category[0].pk
        except:

            category = 0


        if int(category) == 2:
            if state != 's':
                highdefs.append(m)


    return render_to_response('main/HighDefs.html',{'request': request, 'highdefs': highdefs, 'uname' :uname, 'email': email}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

else:
    return(login)
```

Comment: Please don't mix CamelCase with under_score namings. In fact, you should stick to under_score naming convention for functions by PEP8.

Comment: It looks like your view is returning a function instead of an `HttpResponse`. However we can't tell unless you post the code for your view.

Comment: i have edited the post...please check the view

Comment: The post still doesn't show the code that has the actual problem—wherever you're calling has_header, it's not here. Also, it's still returning `login` rather than `login(request)`. Give us a http://sscce.org/ that exhibits the problem you want a fix for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your view must return an `HttpResponse` object.

It does this for one branch of your `if` statement:

```
return render_to_response(...)
```

But not in the `else` branch.

```
return(login)
```

If `login` is a view function that returns an `HttpResponse` object, then you can change your return statement to

```
return login(request)
```

However, I suspect you want to redirect the user to your login page instead. In that case, change your code to:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

where `/login/` is the url of your login page.

Answer (score 4):

The last line of your view is `return login` (don't know why you're wrapping your returns in parentheses, it's unnecessary). But presumably `login` is a function, and you're not calling it. I expect you mean to do `return login()` or `return login(request)`.